# How to add HTML content editor in Django admin view?

Tags: python, html, django, django-admin

How would I add a rich-text HTML content editor in my Django admin view?

For example, if I want to change the content on my homepage, what python code would I have to input for the HTML to be displayed when I log into the admin portal?

I want to be able to view all of my pages (hopefully even be able to add/delete them), and edit the content directly from the admin view. Similar to something like this:

http://feincms-django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_images/item_editor_content.png

I appreciate any and all help! Thank you!

Comment: I think `django-ckeditor` will help https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html shown there is there cuz it is in the database. If what you want is a cms, there are several of those for django like [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/en/), [wagtail](http://wagtail.io/), [mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) among others.

If, on the other hand, you have a model already and want to display it in the admin, you can [register it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import Author

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

In that example, the Author model will show up in admin for edition.

In the last case, where you already have your model registered but you want to have a WYSIWYG editor, check the [django-grid](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/wysiwyg/) for that kind of package and find one suitable, or install one manually.
You have several options in case you want to try the second approach: [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/), [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/), etc.

Comment: In your opinion, which method would you recommend pursuing? Thank you for your input, by the way!

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve...any of those can be valid depending on your needs.